# Javascript node.js regex url matching

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, url

So pretty much I have an inputted URL and I am trying to see if it starts with any of the following URLs:

```
"https://open.spotify.com/playlist/",
"https://www.youtube.com/watch",
"https://youtu.be/",
"https://open.spotify.com/track/",
"https://youtube.com/playlist",
```

So how it should work is if I were to input "https://open.spotify.com/track/1vrd6UOGamcKNGnSHJQlSt?si=61680eaef0ac419e" it would return that it matched "https://open.spotify.com/track/".

If I were to input "https://youtu.be/5qap5aO4i9A" it would return "https://youtu.be/".

So far I have

```
url.match(/^https?:\/\/(www.youtube.com|youtube.com)\/playlist(.*)$/)
url.match(/^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?(m\.)?(youtube\.com|youtu\.?be)\/.+$/gi)
```

but it's not taking me down the right path and I am extremely lost. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to get the specific prefix that matched, checking with [`startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) would probably be simpler than using a regular expression:

```js
const prefixes = [
    "https://open.spotify.com/playlist/",
    "https://www.youtube.com/watch",
    "https://youtu.be/",
    "https://open.spotify.com/track/",
    "https://youtube.com/playlist",
];

function getPrefix(url) {
    const urlLower = url.toLowerCase();
    return prefixes.find((prefix) => urlLower.startsWith(prefix));
}

getPrefix("https://open.spotify.com/track/1vrd6UOGamcKNGnSHJQlSt?si=61680eaef0ac419e"); // "https://open.spotify.com/track/"
getPrefix("https://youtu.be/5qap5aO4i9A"); // "https://youtu.be/"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use regex for that purpose you are using. Since you have all the list of urls you have to match against. You just have to check with the url you receive.

```
const list = ["https://open.spotify.com/playlist/",
  "https://www.youtube.com/watch",
  "https://youtu.be/",
  "https://open.spotify.com/track/",
  "https://youtube.com/playlist",
];

function getMeMatchedURL(url) {
  const matchedURL = list.filter(item => {
    return url.substring(0, item.length) === item;
  });
  console.log(matchedURL);
}

getMeMatchedURL("https://open.spotify.com/track/1vrd6UOGamcKNGnSHJQlSt?si=61680eaef0ac419e");

getMeMatchedURL("https://youtu.be/5qap5aO4i9A");
```

From this you will get the url it matches, if it return empty array then it didn't match any of the list.